# jQuery autocomplete 1.1: Show All Data on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to make [this extension](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) show all data on focus?. I have tried to change minChars to `0` but it only show when the input double clicked.

```
$("#month").autocomplete(months, {
        minChars: 0,
        max: 12,
        autoFill: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        matchContains: false,
        scrollHeight: 220,
        formatItem: function(data, i, total) {
            // don't show the current month in the list of values (for whatever reason)
            if ( data[0] == months[new Date().getMonth()] ) 
                return false;
            return data[0];
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to bind a focus event to the input and call the jQuery UI method as a result. Take a look at [this js fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/eNZ86/1/)

I added the following code:

```
$('#month').autocomplete({
    // Your current code
}).on('focus', function(event) {
    var self = this;
    $(self).autocomplete( "search", this.value);;
});
```

the value passed into the `search` method is what the autocomplete will look for.

**How to search for all values on focus**

If you want all available dropdowns leave it as "" but add `minLength : 0` to the options object.

```
$('#month').autocomplete({
    minLength : 0
}).on('focus', function(event) {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

Comment: Owh, you use current version of jquery-ui. Could it work in [this plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/)?

Comment: What version are you using, as far as I remember not much has changed in autocomplete since it was brought into jQuery UI. Why dont you try it and see if it works?

Comment: I can't change the jquery-ui version in this short time, So I need to make it work in previous autocomplete plugin

Comment: Sooo... this isnt jquery ui at all, this is the old deprecated plugin?

Comment: $(this).autocomplete("search", ""); this is gold !

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, due to this plugin is old (and deprecated), there is very little documentation available for this version.

This worked for me:

```
var __n_clicks = 0;

$("#autocomplete_input").autocomplete(data, {
    minChars: 0,
    ...
}).on('click', function(event) {
    if(__n_clicks < 1){
        __n_clicks++;
        $(this).click();
    }else {
        __n_clicks = 0;   
    }
});
```

executing "dblclick" didn't work either, it had to be 2 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some combobox with this plugin try this:

```html
$('.lookup').on('click', function(event) {
var str =$(this).attr('id');
$('#'+str.slice(1)).focus().click().click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete(availableTags, {
        minChars: 0,
    }).focus(function(event) {
        $(this).click();
    });
```

this could also work for one click only, but it's best to just switch plugin entirely.