# How can I show all tag editor options on input focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tageditor

I have 7 options on my JS array

```
(7) ["tcp-download", "udp-download", "udp-upload", "tcp-upload", "random", "random2", "BeverlyHills"]
```

I also have an input that use tagEditor fn()

[image]

When I first clicked on the input to focus, it's not showing any option at all, ...

[image]

unless I started typing `a` ... for example.

[image]

Is there a way to present all options to my users as soon as they click on the input box?

```
$('#tags').tagEditor({

    autocomplete: {
        delay: 0,
        position: { collision: 'flip' },
        source: options
    },
    forceLowercase: false,
    delimiter: ',', /* space and comma */
    placeholder: 'Ex. tcp-download',
    initialTags: '',
    onChange: function(field, editor, tags) {
        console.log(field, editor, tags);
    },

});
```

## Note

I've looked in their [documentation](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html), I only see **initialTags**.
But what I'm trying to show is the options of those tags not to preselected for my user.

Comment: May you use a stacksnippet to show the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the document its using jqueryui autocomplete.

I found this topic [jQuery autocomplete 1.1: Show All Data on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874214/jquery-autocomplete-1-1-show-all-data-on-focus), Hope this can help.